# Thinking Sphinx Combining :with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, thinking-sphinx

I was wondering how I could combine the result sets of Thinking Sphinx

I have the following query:

```
Model.search :with => {:attribute_1 => id}
```

Which I want to combine with:

```
Model.search :with => {:attribute_2 => id}
```

Is there a neat way to do this with just one search? I could do array addition but that does no seem to be a good solution at all. If I combine the filters like this:

```
Model.search :with => {:attribute_1 => id, :attribute_2 => id}
```

the results are the ***intersection*** of the two filters, which is not the desired output. Is there any way to do an OR operation with the filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really comes down to a limitation in Sphinx - which has no concept of ORs when referencing attributes in filters.

Perhaps you could combine the two attributes together? Then the following would work:

```
Model.search :with => {:attr_1_and_2 => id}
```

In your model, if you're dealing with single values, this will definitely work - and maybe with arrays of values:

```
has [attribute_1, attribute2], :as => :attr_1_and_2
```